# @Transactional Spring Boot test that emulates real commits

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I am using Spring Data Auditing (AuditorAware) on a method that finds, modifies and stores an entity, updating a @LastModifiedDate field. As soon as I annotate the method with @Transactional (in order to avoi side-effects over other tests), it seems to not do anything on my updatable date, I guess due to the fact that the commit is rollbacked at the end before the triggering of auditing listeners in the entity.

How can I solve such scenario and test properly the field is updated without leaving the database in a different state?

I am looking for something like:

```
@Transactional
public void test(){
     xRepository.save(entity); //Real commit here with all the effects, but rollbacked someway after method exits
}
```

Comment: The database should be wiped after your tests.  Are you in a position that you can't cleanly do this?

Comment: Yes, the fact that AuditorListener only seems to be triggered on a complete commit, and that is what I am exactly testing

Comment: There is a question of whether or not you don't actually trust your library of choice to do its job like it declared (more [here](https://blog.frankel.ch/how-to-test-code-that-uses-envers/#gsc.tab=0)). In the end, there is no real way of testing your case via transactional code, because audit appears only after it's committed. So, If you want to test audit, you have to create transaction and commit it manually.

Comment: Can you post your test class?  You *might* have an annotation or two which would automatically trigger a rollback.

Comment: Sorry it seems it works with @CreateDate, I'll do some more forensics before I mess with the case

Comment: did you try to call the `flush` method with the entityManager to force the persistence of the data in the database

Comment: Yes, still does not work, but it does for CreatedDate, probably it's a bug or a ocmplex transactional thing